Is Tech House a subgenre of Deep House?
I noticed Tech House songs are in some music websites detected as Deep House . As far as I understand, for what I've seen music producers talk about it, what makes Tech House songs is kicks separated equally, with a clap over each two, and a hit hat a beat before the clap, with the presence of other percussion instruments optional. And Deep House songs seems to have a similar pattern, kicks separated equally, with some other instrument each 2, it could be claps, but also snares or snaps, and the hit hat in the beat before can be missing, this is what I've concluded. Is this right?
Is Tech House a subgenre of Deep House? What differentiates them?

What differentiates them?

Deep house and tech house songs have a sound emphasis difference. Deep house songs usually emphasize a spacious use of percussion/muted bassline or deep bassline/soft-sounding pads/soulful vocals. Tech house songs usually combine the sound emphasis of the genres techno and house.

Source: [Deep House vs. Tech House: The Differences Between the Two Genres – Passion for EDM

Deep House is characterized by its use of soulful vocals, smooth basslines, and atmospheric melodies. It often incorporates elements of jazz, funk, and gospel music and has a laid-back, groovy feel. On average the bpm will be between 120 and 125 for Deep House music.


Tech House, on the other hand, is characterized by its use of mechanical, robotic-sounding beats and percussion. It often has a more stripped-down, minimal sound compared to Deep House and tends to be more focused on the beat and groove. Tech House tracks may also incorporate elements of techno, House, and other electronic music genres. On average the bpm will be between 120 and 130 for Tech House music.


Overall, the main difference between Deep House and Tech House is the feel and atmosphere of the music. Deep House is typically more soulful and atmospheric, while Tech House is more mechanical and focused on the beat.

Source: What is the difference between Deep House and Tech House?
